# Copy files into newly created folders on partial filename match

Tags: powershell

Hi all reaching out because I've reached the limits of my powershell knowledge.

I have a directory that has over 200,000 files, I need to copy all files that have a partial match to the filename into folders that I have already created using this script

```
Set-Location "C:\Users\joshh\Documents\Testing Environment" 
$Folders = Import-Csv "C:\Users\joshh\Documents\Weichert.csv" 
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
New-Item "myfilepathhere\$($Folder.folderName)" -type directory 
}
```

UPDATED:
Here is a sample of the filenames:

```
TH-246-02050-LOL-SQ-ALT2.png
TH-246-02050-WHT-H.png
TH-247-02050-EMB-LOD.png
TH-246-02050-LOL-H-ALT2.png
TH-246-02050-LOL-SQ.png
TH-246-02050-LOL-SQ-ALT.png
TH-247-02050-EMB-LOD-ALT.png
TH-247-02050-EMB-LOL.png
TH-247-02050-EMB-LOL-ALT.png
TH-247-02050-LOD-H.png
```

Above is an example of what the filenames look like, I need to copy all files containing -EMB- and move them into folders in another directory that match the first 12 characters of that filename (ex. TH-247-02050)

UPDATED:
And if a folder doesn't exist create a folder with the first 12 characters of the filename.
Mind you the first 12 characters have many variants some start with RM, KW, etc.

This is what I have so far and what I know but I know the Move-Item portion isn't exactly what I want it to do

```
$source = "targetPath"
$destination = "targetPath2"

$embFiles = @(Get-ChildItem ${source}/*EMB* -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
foreach($file in $embFiles) {
    if($file | Where-Object { $_ -clike "*EMB*" }){
    Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination
        }
}
```

Any and all help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: You need to do this only for the `*-EMB-*` files or do the same using the same logic for all the files? also, it would be nice if you add a list of example file names as plain text instead of a screenshot

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ahh yes I'm sorry, I just updated the post to include the plain text filenames and a second updated portion just below the filenames that I originally forgot. And this is just for the files that contain `*-EMB-*` .  Thank you!

Comment: So you want `If($file.name -clike '*EMB*'){Move-Item $file.fullname -Dest (join-path '.\' $file.name.substring(0,12))}` yes?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician if I'm reading/understanding that correctly yes, but also while creating a new folder if folder of `$file.name.substring(0,12)` does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

1. Get all files that contain `-EMB-` in their names: `-Filter *-EMB-* -File`.
2. Group all this files by everything before `-EMB-`, here we can use [`Group-Object -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-group-objects-in-a-hash-table) and a calculated expression using [`Regex.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-6.0). See https://regex101.com/r/iOoBJS/1 for details.
3. Loop through the **Keys** of the *hash table*, each **Key** will be the **Name** Destination folder of the group of files (i.e.: `TH-247-02050`).
4. Join the destination path (`$destinationPath2`) with the name of the destination folder (`$folder`), here we can use [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.2) and check if this joined path exists, if it doesn't, create a new folder with [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2).
5. Lastly, we can move all the files (the **Values** of each **Key** from the hash table) to their corresponding destination.

```
$source      = "targetPath"
$destination = "targetPath2"

$map = Get-ChildItem $source -Filter *-EMB-* -File | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString {
    [regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '(?i).+(?=-EMB-)').Value
}

foreach($folder in $map.Keys) {
    $d = Join-Path $destination -ChildPath $folder
    $d = New-Item $d -ItemType Directory -Force
    # -WhatIf can be removed once you have checked the script is doing what you want
    $map[$folder] | Move-Item -Destination $d -WhatIf -Verbose
}
```

`-AsString` is needed in Windows PowerShell due to a bug.

Comment: Just a note, `$d = New-Item $d -ItemType Directory -Force` will create the folder if it's not there, and return the folder either way, so you *could* skip testing for it. It won't harm anything if the folder exists. Not sure how much that would actually speed things up, but it might if there's a lot of iterations.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hey! So I love your script but is there a way I can only grab the files with the extension .pdf ? Looks like the script grabbed both the .png and .pdf and I only need the pdf

Comment: @JoshuaHuezo sure, try using this filter, `-Filter *-EMB-*.pdf`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Ahhh yessss! Thank you x a billion!!